# import de.polygonal.graphics.VectorRenderer

Tags: actionscript, flash-builder, actionscript-3

how to import (de.polygonal.graphics.VectorRenderer) 
in this link http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=916  this is the component  https://github.com/polygonal/gl

Answer (score 0):

Add the package/class to the path of your .fla file, if you're using Flash Professional. Otherwise, add it to the root of the project.

Comment: actually i am using flash builder ,i added it to the root but project cant read it ,could you help please ??

Comment: Are you adding the import line to your project?

Comment: I mean import [package].[class];

Comment: yes ,i did ,but the import cant read the package and classes ,take a look please at the links .classes are (.hx) not (.as) ,is this the problem ?? ,if it is ,how to fix ??

Comment: .hx seems to be the extension for [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) files. I'm not entirely sure about their use in Flash Builder. Try changing .hx to .as or something, if that doesn't help then I have no idea :(.

Comment: didn't try that ,i 'll ofcourse ,but i dont think that this is the problem ,the project cant read all the package not the .hx classes

Comment: Do you get any errors when you try to debug/compile the project? You should edit your question with any errors to help find the problem.

Comment: i didnt get any errors ,the problem is just the import !

Comment: But if you've told flash to import it and there's a problem, I'm sure there would be a compile error. What leads you to believe there is a problem with the import?

Comment: cant be shown in the autocomplete ,and even if i handled it ,it show me warning as it is not found !!

Comment: Seems my flash doesn't want to import a .hx file either, so I can't help you :(. Sorry dude.

Comment: You might decide to find an AS3 version of the package. There is a link to it in the comments, but the code library appears to be dead already. So, you're probably out of luck, sorry.